# Password manager that uses a mix of long and short key derivation functions

Tags: password-management, kdf

I was reading "A Convenient Method for Securely Managing Passwords, Halderman et al., 2005". In short, the authors say to do the following:

```
cache = very_long_key_derivation_function(salt,master_password)
save the cache on disk
password_for_site_a = short_key_derivation_function(salt,site_a|master_password|cache)
password_for_site_b = short_key_derivation_function(salt,site_b|master_password|cache)
```

where

- very_long_key_derivation_function is some key derivation functions tuned to require approx 2 minutes
- short_key_derivation_function is some key derivation functions tuned to require 1 second.

This forbids to site_a to brute force the secret in order to find the password of site_b (since each try requires 2 minutes), still allowing fast time to calculate the password of a website. If the cache file is stolen, is still necessary to guess the master_password to know the derived passwords.

There are two problems with this method:

- the master_password is used each time the user needs the password of a certain site
- in order to change the master password (it is used often, it could be seen), all the derived passwords must be changed

I would like to modify the schema in the following way:

```
k1 = very_long_key_derivation_function(salt,master_password_1)
k2 = short_key_derivation_function(salt,master_password_2)
cache = k1 xor k2
save cache on disk
password_for_site_a = short_key_derivation_function(salt,site_a|(cache xor k2))
password_for_site_b = short_key_derivation_function(salt,site_b|(cache xor k2))
```

In this way master_password_1 is used only once (the first time the password manager is used), while master_password_2 is used each time the user needs a password for a site. The derived passwords do not depend on master_password_2. Assuming that master_password_1 can not be stolen (since it is used only once), in order to steal a site password both the cache file and master_password_2 are needed. Also, it is possible to change master_password_2 if the user suspects that somebody saw him writing it, by computing:

```
k1 = very_long_key_derivation_function(salt,master_password_1)
k3 = short_key_derivation_function(salt,master_password_3)
cache = k1 xor k3.
save cache on disk
```

when the user will use master_password_3 the derived site passwords will be the same as before.

I would use some string derived from the username as a salt, and argon2 as key derivation function. Do you think this could be a good method to manage passwords?

Comment: A note on that possible duplicate: I know the underlying hash details differ significantly. But note the main problem with such schemes isn't security of the algorithm, it's usability. And we all know what happens when you sacrifice usability for security....

Comment: Also see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115243/how-secure-is-this-process-for-creating-passwords and others...variants of this question get asked ALL THE TIME.

Comment: Please avoid posting [the same question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/37194/23581) on multiple StackExchange websites. The issue here is that either you link website password to some per-site secret stored locally, in this case the easiest is just for this secret to be the actual password, or as you stated on [crypto.se] you want to go to some "zero storage" way, but an attacker, knowing one of your password, may deduce the master password and/or the other passwords (practically getting any password will be nearly equivalent of getting your complete password store).